# How to find if my codebase is upto date?

Tags: svn, version-control

We have svn repository with a structure like

```
-- trunk
|
-- tags
  |
   - 4.0.0
   |
   - 4.0.1
   |
   - 4.0.2
   |
   - 4.0.2b
```

Now if I go to production site into a directory with the tag 4.0.2b and do `svn info` I get what you can see below. What I understood is that the revision numbers (`Revision: 13107` and `Last Changed Rev: 13104`)  are different because somebody committed something somewhere.

My question is **how can I know** that the 4.0.2b is upto date = **tag with the latest code**? Can I find out without doing `svn up`?

```
URL: svn+ssh://tigs@repository.server.com.au/sever/lib/svne2/edumate2/tags/4.0.2b
Repository Root: svn+ssh://tigs@repository.edumate.com.au/var/lib/svne2/edumate2
Repository UUID: edccd8aa-08f3-0310-ac9a-cddb71435de8
Revision: 13107
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: kon
Last Changed Rev: 13104
Last Changed Date: 2012-02-17 13:31:43 +1100 (Fri, 17 Feb 2012)
```

**NOTE:**
We commit to tags quick fix of bugs.

Comment: Which revision numbers are different?

Comment: `Revision: 13107` and `Last Changed Rev: 13104`

Comment: If I understand you right, you're asking "How can I tell my working copy is update to date without doing svn update?" ? (feel free to use this as the question title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn status --show-updates` (or `svn stat -u` for short) will show any changes that are on the server version of your branch/tag that an `svn update` would pull.

Comment: And then I am after file with `*` or `M` character in front of the file name? Not after files that are having character `?` in front of the file name?

Comment: See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html for a detailed explanation what which symbol means.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking to find out if you are up-to-date, a `svn update` is just a bit too much because it actually performs the update (which is a change, and not just information).

Try `svn status -u` and you will get the information without the side-effects.

Now, if you want to find out if a tag is the "latest code" remember that tags are nothing more than copies into special directories, and as such they shouldn't be allowed subsequent updates.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `svn status -u`, which shows a list of changes in the repository that don't exist in your current working copy.

It basically shows you what a `svn up` would do without pulling the changes into the working copy.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer their question though.  Imagine they'd asked about branches instead (exactly the same thing, just a different usage convention).

Comment: I added a note to my question. We commit quick fixes to tags.

Comment: Updated answer after the clarification in the question.